# I found an RSA private key on my ransomware-infected device. Can I use it to decrypt the files?

Tags: malware, ransomware

I have ransomware on my laptop. I ran Spyhunter and deleted as much as I could. I found an RSA in the Windows registry with `regedit`. Then, as I was checking for unknown files, I found a `.android` file which I opened using notepad. adbkey opened to reveal `---begin private key` and ended with `---end private key`. Lots of numbers, letters, slashes, etc. Did I stumble upon the decryption key? And if so, how do I apply it to decrypt my files?

Comment: Do you make regular backups?

Answer (score 3):

Probably not. Your question is unclear (also because of the bad spelling):

1. What is this "rsa" you found in the registry?
2. I assume that by ".android" and "adbkey" you mean the file `%USERPROFILE%\.android\adbkey`.

It sounds like you stumbled upon a file created by `adb` (Android Debug Bridge, used to control devices in developer mode). This is the key that `adb` uses to identify itself to connected Android devices. On your Android device, you get a prompt whether to trust the computer, and you can store it for next time. To prove, next time, that it is the same computer, the computer has a key which it uses for authentication.

The "lots of numbers, letters and slashes" is usually [base64 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), by the way. It often (but not always) has equals-signs at the end.

Sorry I cannot help you further, but hopefully that at least answers your question.

Comment: thank you-i did not know what what it was. i  was hoping that it would help me find key to decrypt my  files.at my wits end.rsa is a key made by cyber criminals and is in registry

Comment: @colscotty4648 That "rsa" entry in the registry, could you edit your question with a screenshot of that?